# Send email repeatedly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am currently creating a system in my internship using Codeigniter. This system will be able the user to create a service request. After creating the request, an email will be sent automatically to the approver(another user), to notify him of the request. (This has already been implemented). Then the approver will decide whether to approve or disapprove the request. Now, my new assignment is that the approver will receive frequent notifications in his email ( every 30 mins)  if he still hasn't approve/disapprove the request in the system. How will I make this possible?

Comment: By setting up a simple cron job that starts a script on a periodic base which checks if the job has been done.

Comment: how do i start cron job, im on a remote server?

Comment: Depends on what you actually mean by "im on a remote server". If that means you are logged in and have an interactive shell, then use the `crontab` command, I'd say. It is well documented. Read the man page: `man crontab`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a controller with a function which check status of approval and send email if not approved.

eg.

```
class checkapproval extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
      // Database query to fetch all pending approval.
      // $records = $this->db->where('status !=','approve')->get('table_name');
      // foreach($records as $record){
      // send email
      // updated email timestamp in databse for record
      // }
    }
}
```

Now, our next step is to execute this `index` every 30 minutes. Here's cron job we required.

we need to set command in cron job as below which executed every 30 minutes.

```
$php /path/to/project/index.php checkapproval index
```

for more details regarding codeigniter CLI look [HERE](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/cli.html)

Comment: my problem is that we are just connected to a remote server using filezilla,

Comment: @CrystalGrace You might need to get cPanel access to setup cron job. second solution is, you need to get second machine that on 24x7 and call that controller method with url every 30 minutes. In this case, we might need to deal with php call timeout problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a field in your DB against this user which counts the number of times he has been emailed and the timestamp when the last email was sent....and then a cron-tabbed script (running once every 30 mins) will check to see if the user has taken action on the request....and if not; send out another email and update the DB fields with the number of emails sent (incremented) and the unix timestamp when the new email was sent out.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a cron job to perform this. 
A script which checks whether there is unhandled request or not.
Then if he has unhandled request, send him an email.

Comment: how do i use cron job if i'm in a remote server?

Comment: If you are at a hosting company, these usually have an administrator interface for this.
If you use a vpn, you may use crontab in the shell.